Superset DB initialization failing, causing superset-app to restart multiple time on VM

So apparearantly when running superset via docker-compose on local machine and a linux VM is bit different if we are running the application using docker compose up.
docker compose up runs fine on local machine.
docker compose up - Initialize the containers, but the superset-app contaihner keeps restarting. When looking into the error logs it says unable to resolve host db. This refers to the DATABASE_HOST in .env file.
The root cause for this issue is the difference in how the etc/hosts file is setup for VMs.
Local file:

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

whereas the VM will have only allowed IP, and I believe the issue happens when the VM tries to initialize DB instance and tries to get ip for db DATABASE_HOST and this isn't resolved because of missing localhost config on the VMs generally
